# want to create ubuntu FTP mirror

Tags: ftp

Requirement:
I want to copy the contents of Ubuntu FTP site.

Problem description:
I used "wget" to download files from ftp site but "wget" is very slow and takes long time.

Solution requested:
what are the best and fast way to copy files from ftp site. what is the size of current FTP sites us.archive.ubuntu.com and security.ubuntu.com.

Comment: The slowth comes not from `wget`, but the network. Is your MTU right for your connection? What is your connection? Have you specified multiple URIs to `wget`. What does `tracepath -n Ubuntu FTP site` tell you?

Comment: The size of the current archives is about 65 GB (each), but don't pin me down on this

Comment: Thanks waltinator and grooveplex, Not sure about MTU (how do i check or specify MTU value)? i am directly connecting to external world (internet) using Reliance USB modem (12 MBps). Yes i have specified 2 URIs to wget, tracepath out put (gethostbyname2: Unknown host). One question is wget works faster or apt-mirror is faster (are both depends on network speed?)